# Error converting string to JSON object

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to fetch some data from mysql database to android. In the code below the output is shown on the logcat using 'tagconvertstr' but there's an error that the string can not be converted to json object.

```
try
{
    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject("question");
    name=(json_data.getString("question"));                         
    newq(name);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post the value of result

Comment: Actually i'm fetching a question from mysql, the value is printed using 'tagconvertstr' which is : 11-06 00:47:45.523: I/tagconvertstr(1849): [{"questions":[{"question":"Where is the Largest Pyramid in the world?"}]}

Comment: this line json_data.getString("question") will return an json object but you try to get string thats y its giving error

Comment: then would you please tell me, how can i print the string that i get in the 'result' variable??, because if i directly try to print value using setText(result) then it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: take my edited answer, i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
try {
                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
                    JSONArray jsonResult = new JSONArray(result);

        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("question");

                name=jsonObject.getString("question");
        newq(name);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                }
```

Comment: :( now it is saying that, org.json.JSONException: Value [{"question":"Where is the Largest Pyramid in the world?"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: ys frnd, i hv directly replaced the code with your code..:) but the error is still there.

Comment: what is exact value of result which is you got from mysql, please post again

Comment: This is result's value:- 11-06 04:00:50.037: I/tagconvertstr(1436): [{"questions":{"question":"Where is the Largest Pyramid in the world?"}} 
11-06 04:00:50.037: I/tagconvertstr(1436): ]
 , which is not getting converted into jasonObject or JsonArray.

Comment: now it says, 11-06 04:21:55.301: E/Fail 3(1640): org.json.JSONException: No value for question

Comment: write questions instead of question in this line JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("question");

Comment: sorry but not working dude.,again saying JSONArray can not be converted to JSONObject even after renaming to questions..

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(response.toString());
 String responseserver = json_data.getString("responseCode");     
 System.out.println(responseserver);
```

Comment: it throws an Exception saying 'No value for question'.

Comment: dude can i see your response string

Comment: JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result.toString());
          String responseserver = json_data.getString("question");     
          System.out.println(responseserver);

Comment: 11-06 05:46:24.929: D/dalvikvm(2324): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 9% free 2968K/3228K, paused 225ms, total 245ms
11-06 05:46:25.217: D/gralloc_goldfish(2324): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-06 05:48:53.606: E/pass 1(2324): connection success 
11-06 05:48:54.156: E/pass 2(2324): connection success 
11-06 05:48:54.297: I/tagconvertstr(2324): [{"questions":{"question":"Where is the Largest Pyramid in the world?"}} 
11-06 05:48:54.297: I/tagconvertstr(2324): ]
11-06 05:48:54.347: E/Fail 3(2324): org.json.JSONException: No value for question

Comment: chnge questions inplace of question

Comment: oops now it says  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
and it prints the value using system.out.print

Comment: try to clear and rebuilt ur code.it works.and surround your code with try/catch